# How to console.log only item in this js

Tags: javascript

I like to console.log only item. but I don't know how

```js
let cart_items = [{
    id: 1,
    item: "Android Mobile",
    cost: 7650
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    item: "iphone Mobile",
    cost: 56000
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    item: "windowes Mobile",
    cost: 3000
  }
];

let result = cart_items.filter((value) => value.cost < 10000);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: `console.log(result[0])`? It's not clear what you want from us.

Comment: what is the problem? 2 items are less than 10000

Comment: you can use `find()` if you only want 1 item. filter will give you array of object.

Comment: You can also loop through your object and log `iterator["item"]`

Comment: Use map `cart_items.filter((value) => value.cost < 10000).map({item})=>item);`

Comment: `let result = cart_items.filter((value) => value.cost < 10000).map((value)=> value.item);`
Array functions can be combined
or
`let results = cart_items.reduce((acc,curr)=>{ if(curr.cost< 10000){ acc.push(curr.item);} return acc; },[])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `.forEach` on the result array.

```js
let cart_items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    item: "Android Mobile",
    cost: 7650,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    item: "iphone Mobile",
    cost: 56000,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    item: "windowes Mobile",
    cost: 3000,
  },
];

let result = cart_items.filter((value) => value.cost < 10000);
result.forEach((value) => console.log(value.item));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let res of result) {
  console.log(res.item);
}
```

**Output**

> Android Mobile
>
> windowes Mobile

Answer (score -1):

```
result.forEach((element)=> {
    console.log(element.item);
});
```